# Export and import schema from one data to another

Tags: oracle11g, database-administration, ora-12170

I am trying to export and import schema from one data to another but I get this error:

```
[oracle@localhost Desktop]$ impdp shishu/shishu@demo directory=data remap_schema=shishu:user2 dumpfile=shishu.dmp logfile=user2.log

Import: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Wed Mar 2 23:18:57 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

UDI-12170: operation generated ORACLE error 12170 

ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to be more concise. I also indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. Ping at required host to check if you can reach it
2. Try `tnsping demo` command, if not worked then check `tnsnames` file
3. If above worked then check firewall.
4. If all set and it is a matter of slow network you can change `SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT`, `SQLNET.SEND_TIMEOUT` and `SQLNET.RECV_TIMEOUT` in `sqlnet.ora` to larger values.

Reference :
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12170_tns_connect_timeout.htm